# Unable to render data from .ts to mat-table or in general html file in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class ScanServeripsService {
    constructor(
          private http: HttpClient, private httpUtils: HttpUtilsService,
        public env: EnvService
     ) { }
    
    API_FILE_URL = this.env.apiUrl + '/api/something/';

    getPerFile(id: any, itemid: any): Observable<any> {
        if(servid & fileid) {
            return this.http.get(this.API_FILE_URL + '?id=' + `${id}` + '&itemid=' + `${itemid}`);
    }
}
```

.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { MyService } from '../../_core/services';

export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
    dataSource: any;
    itemID: any;
    displayedColumns = ['match', 'type']

    constructor(
        private ActivatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
        private _router: Router,
        private myService: MyService
    ){}
    
    ngOnInit() {
        this.ActivatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(paramas => {
            const id = paramas.file;
            this.itemID = paramas.itemid;
            this.myService.getPerFile(id, this.itemID).subscribe(res => {
                this.dataSource = res["data"]; // When i do console log .. I'm getting the correct result.
            });
        });
    }  
}
```

response from api

```
[
{
   id: 1,
   match: 'Something',
   type: 'something'
},
{...},
{...}
]
```

html file

```
<ng-container mPortletBody>
            <div class="mat-table__wrapper">
                <mat-table class="lmat-elevation-z8" [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort matSortActive="id" matSortDirection="asc" matSortDisableClear *ngIf="dataSource">

                    <ng-container matColumnDef=""match>
                        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="width:70%;">Path</mat-header-cell>
                        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let customer" style="cursor:pointer;width:70%;" (click)="goPer(customer.id)">{{ customer.match}}</mat-cell>
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="type">
                        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef  style="width:15%;">Entity</mat-header-cell>
                        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let customer" style="cursor:pointer;width:15%;">{{ customer.type}}</mat-cell>
                    </ng-container>

                <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
                <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></mat-row>
            </mat-table>

        </div>

</ng-container>
```

Not able to figure out where I'm doing wrong and what i'm doing wrong. I did exactly what doc mentioned. Getting result from api when i do console log but not able render it in html file. Pls help me out. Question has been updated.

Angular material version = 6.4.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is happening because you haven't imported matTableDataSource

so try importing : `import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';`
and change Line: `dataSource: MatTableDataSource<any>;`

and try changing line: `this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(res.data);`

Comment: To be honest, I'm not able to access "dataSource" in html page

Comment: answer has been edited please checkout. hope this will work.

Comment: not working .. I even tried <div *ngFor="let data of dataScource"><p>{{data.match}}</p></div> but not working. Seems like dataSource is not rendering in html file

Comment: check if the data coming as response is array or not because dataSource only works on array of data. and try with my last edited answer.

Comment: in response to api request i'm getting res = {"length": 10, "data": [{"match": "something", "type": "something", "score": "10"},{...}, {...} ...]}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232382/discussion-between-purvang-gor-and-sharath-nayak).